# how to display VOIP call screen above Always On Display screen?

Tags: android, call, sip, voip, pjsip

I'm using PJSIP library for VOIP calls, and I have a problem when I get a VoIP call.

When the phone is locked or unlocked everything works fine.

But if Always On Screen (AOD) is turn on I can hear the ringtone but I can't see the screen with the buttons for an answer or decline the call.

Here are the flags I used to show the VOIP call screen when the phone is locked:

> FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
>   FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
>   FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
>   FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON

and permissions:

> "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
>   "android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"

Thank you all!